# Из сочинения ученицы

Tags: однородные-члены

Писали сочинение с моей ученицей. Не могу уверенно сказать, правильно ли она составила эту фразу, подскажите (интересует именно однородный ряд)

> Актриса, игравшая Лену Чехову, прекрасно справилась со своей ролью:
> она сумела вызвать сочувствие к своему персонажу и негатив к "уродам"
> из класса коррекции!

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147985/discussion-on-question-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.